# ACF - User.php filter or aciton

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using wordpress with Advanced Custom Fields plugin v4.4.2
I need to modify the user select fields, so that it displays not only `display_name`, but also the `user_login`.

I found the bit of code that handles this, and it is here:

> wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/core/fields/user.php on line 223

And i changed the default code from:

```
$field['choices'][ $label ][ $user->ID ] = ( $user->display_name );
```

to:

```
$field['choices'][ $label ][ $user->ID ] = ucfirst($user->user_login) . ' - ' . ucfirst( $user->display_name );
```

Now, everything's working fine, but, as you probably already know, changing core files it's not the best way to modifying things in wordpress, but i have to use filters or actions.

Now, simple question, is there a filter or action that allows me to change this bit?

I searched a lot but i couldn't find anything useful.
thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly go through this plugin and I found that (although I haven't tested this) :
There is a filter **acf/load_field_defaults**. This filter hook can be used for this purpose.

> I found this in file core/fields/_functions.php line number 546

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't really use this filter, but i used acf/load_field/key=field_54063053c9c4a instead. This allows me to apply filters specific for fields. Thanks a lot anyway for pointing me in the right direction!